# I am the hunter

Tags: riddle

I am the hunter.

Many believe my time has come. I do not decide when, or how, or why I will die, but when I do, I will do so with a ferocity that will set the heavens ablaze, and all shall marvel at my glory. My shoulder has been one that many stood on for centuries, and when it doesn't, it will make finding your way difficult.

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be

> the constellation ORION

Because

> Orion is the hunter
>  When Betelguise, his shoulder star, goes supernova (maybe soon), those who use it to guide them, will need to find a different star to use.

Comment: Nicely done, mate! That’s quite fast

Comment: Thanks. I'm a fount of knowledge. Also, this particular rot13(pbafgryyngvba) has always been my favorite.